# Using multiple URLs inside htaccess RewriteCond

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm using the following code inside my .htaccess file to prevent certain URL from being served from https. How can I modify this code to include additional URLs? For example, I don't want the about page to load from https either. Adding an extra line similar to the careers link didn't work.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
# Go to https if not on careers
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =80 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/careers/[\s?] [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/capital/[\s?] [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/summer/[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]

# Go to http if you are on careers
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !=80 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /careers/[\s?] [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /capital/[\s?] [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /summer/[\s?] [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: You can specify multiple `RewriteCond`, and use the `[OR]` flag if necessary (otherwise an implicit AND is used, which means they must all match.)

Comment: Can you show me an example of how you'd use the OR flag?

Comment: Try yourself first please. (You’ll only want to use it for the positive matches though.)

Comment: I tried it by putting an [OR] at the end of URL lines (after the NC flag) and it didn't work.

Comment: If you need to use multiple flags, they go into the brackets comma-separated, `[NC,OR]` (seriously, the documentation mentions that, and you used it for your `RewriteRule` already …)

Comment: updated my question with the new code, it gives me the "The page isn't redirecting properly" error on the browser.

Comment: What did I just say about using the flag only on the positive matches …?

Answer (score 1):

Better use regex alternation and minimize your code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
# Go to https if not on careers
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =80 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/(careers|capital|summer)/[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]

# Go to http if you are on careers
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !=80 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(careers|capital|summer)/[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
</IfModule>
```